# No Payload Detected when using JMeter with a REST Webservice and XML body

Tags: http-post, jmeter

I am using JMeter to do load-testing. My test consists of a simple POST request. When I perform this request, the server, in its error logs, says `No Payload Detected`. I have verified that the server is receiving a Post request, and I have tried different texts in the Raw Post Body.

Next, to make sure it wasn't a problem with the server, I used a different Http Request program (Wiztools rest client) to send off a post with the same content. It works, and no `No Payload Detected` error is thrown.

My current theory is that both JMeter and the server do parsing. I know the server does, as it is looking for a small piece of data, and that JMeter's parsing ruins that small piece of data.

So, in conclusion, my question is "What parsing does JMeter do?".
I've looked for this answer, and the only thing I know that it does parse is `${VARNAME}`.

The text I am sending is below:

```
<IpReport xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="">
  <ProductReviewId>12345</ProductReviewId>
  <DepartmentCode>ABC</DepartmentCode>
  <ProductTitle>Test of a teaser</ProductTitle>
  <ProjectId>2</ProjectId>
  <ProductCodePD>ICS-1139150</ProductCodePD>
  <Priority>Pre-Approved</Priority>
  <Status>Approved</Status>
  <IpStatus>Submitted</IpStatus>
  <EvalStatus>Approved</EvalStatus>
  <EvalNotes>No Limitations - message from eval</EvalNotes>
  <Notes>Notes test</Notes>
  <IsInClarity>true</IsInClarity>
  <IsPreRelease>true</IsPreRelease>
  <IsApproved>true</IsApproved>
  <IsCOREvalIP>false</IsCOREvalIP>
  <Elements>
    <IpReportElement>
      <IpReportElementLineItemId>21774</IpReportElementLineItemId>
      <ElementType>ReportingStatement</ElementType>
      <Contributor>Sample Contributor</Contributor>
      <Description>test</Description>
      <LocationInProduct>test</LocationInProduct>
      <ReportingStatementId>7</ReportingStatementId>
      <IpCodeId>3</IpCodeId>
      <Links>
        <IpReportLink>
          <IpReportLinkId>25982</IpReportLinkId>
          <Name>Link</Name>
          <Url>https://example.org/</Url>
        </IpReportLink>
      </Links>
    </IpReportElement>
  </Elements>
  <CustomData>&lt;site&gt;ldsorg&lt;/site&gt;
&lt;site-root&gt;/preview/ldsorg/&lt;/site-root&gt;
&lt;correlation-document-id&gt;123456-eng&lt;/correlation-document-id&gt;
&lt;post-to-server&gt;l12773:9239&lt;/post-to-server&gt;
</CustomData>
  <ApprovalNumber>2013-1139150-I</ApprovalNumber>
  <EvalApprovalNumber>2013-1139150-E</EvalApprovalNumber>
</IpReport>
```

Here is an screenshot of JMeter. This is the only request, with no other config elements:
[image: JMeter Screenshot]

Comment: Show your HTTP Sampler configuration

Comment: http://img607.imageshack.us/img607/4645/20130506104835telerikvm.png There's a screenshot of the request.  I have verified that the server and port are correct.  I do not have any config elements.

Comment: You can add image in your question, I am not able to display the link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may also need to add an [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to set some header like content-type:

[image: Adding an HTTP Header]

Comment: I don't believe it has to do with headers, as the wiztools rest client isn't sending it with any headers.  (I'm also not sure what key/value I would use)

Comment: This answer was right.  Content-Type needed to be application/xml

Comment: thanks much! Didn't know that HTTP Header Manager should be placed as a child. When I placed before HTTP sampler in sampler's tree view, that didn't  work for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all. In your question above, both in screenshot and in request text part of request has symbols `<` and `>` encoded and part - not. And you are using Content Encoding = UTF-8 in addition. Seems that in this situation request will be sent malformed.
   You can add e.g. [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and check how the request is sent from jmeter.
2. You can try dedicated [REST Sampler](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/RESTSampler) as well.

Comment: No need for Rest sampler for this in my opinion.

Comment: The information in the <CustomData> is the important info, and it is intentional that we are using &lt and &gt.  In the Results Tree, the request does not convert the symbols to <>.

Comment: Ok, I just ran a compare on the Request in the View Results Tree and the raw data, and it looks like they are identical.